# How to convert PersistableBundle to Bundle in android?

Tags: android, bundle, android-jobscheduler

I am looking for a way to convert PersistableBundle to Bundle in android. Is there any simpler way to do this? They both do not inherit from same class and hence i cannot typecast them.

Edit:

I found this way to copy

```
public static Bundle getBundleFromPersistableBundle(final PersistableBundle persistableBundle) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if(persistableBundle == null) {
        return null;
    }
    bundle.putAll(persistableBundle);
    return bundle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a Bundle from a PersistableBundle instance.

```
PersistableBundle pb = new PersistableBundle();
Bundle b = new Bundle(pb);
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#Bundle(android.os.PersistableBundle)) for this constructor:

> Constructs a Bundle containing a copy of the mappings from the given PersistableBundle. Does only a shallow copy of the PersistableBundle -- see deepCopy() if you don't want that.

Comment: I found a way to do this:
public static Bundle getBundleFromPersistableBundle(final PersistableBundle persistableBundle) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if(persistableBundle == null) {
            return null;
        }
        bundle.putAll(persistableBundle);
        return bundle;
    }

Comment: This code snippet will create & discard a Bundle unnecessarily if it's called with a `null` PersistableBundle argument.  Check for the null argument *first,* and only allocate the Bundle if you are actually going to return one.

Comment: @ctate this code snippet also defines the PeristableBundle, so it is by definition not null

Comment: I'm referring to the snippet in user2267399's comment, not yours.  Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @ctate oh ok, no problem